# air for android icon size too small

Tags: android, air, icons, size

I'm using Air 3.7.1860 for android. I publish app and install on the Galaxy S3, but the icon size is too small. I use Air for Android Settings, but it has only 3 types of icons file 36x36 ,48x48 and 72x72. Please help.

Comment: What is the Air?
I find answer for my question "Adobe Integrated Runtime (AIR), also known as Adobe AIR, is a cross-platform runtime environment developed by Adobe Systems for building applications targeting desktop, mobile and television systems using Adobe Flash, Adobe Flex, ActionScript 3.0, MXML, HTML, or AJAX."

Comment: Yes I mean Flash AIR but I'm asking about icon size not what is AIR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and now found the solution. Download the latest AIR beta 4.0 SDK (works with 3.9 either) from http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/air.html

1. In your flash project, set everything up in the publish screens.
2. Under include files, add the 96x96 icon and the 144x144 icon.
3. Close publish dialogs.
4. Manually edit the manifest to add in the 96 and 144 icons
5. Close XML
6. Goto file XML descriptor properties - change to read-only
7. Back to Flash and File - Publish

Comment: You are right man! Thank you so much. I have been having this problem for year. I want to mark your answer as useful but I don't have enough rep. ;(

Comment: Can you offer some screenshots? And a bit of a more step by step. This would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss two resource folder in you project:

- **drawable-xhdpi** where icon 96x96px
- **drawable-xxhdpi** where icon 144x144px

More info at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size)

**UPDATE**: If you have no such folder, just try to add it by your hands in project tree and add proper icon. Or try new version of AIR SDK.

Comment: I'm using Flash Air not Android SDK so these folder doesn't have.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add by hand? I tried AIR 3.8 too, but there is only 3 type of icon size.

Comment: go to windows file explorer, find your project folder, go to resource folder. You should see folder drawable-hdpi and other. And create folder in windows/linux/MAC.

Comment: We are building with Adobe AIR SDK, not Android SDK (eclipse or something else). So, There is no such folders in the projects.